# Pinescript, find upper and lower range for current indicator (in separate window)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using Pinescript in Tradingview. I have created a library, containing a function that draws Vertical Lines at suitable intervals depending on which period the chart is shown in.

I am using Version 5, and the code to draw the actual line is using line.new:

```
if (draw == true)
    line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, close * 1.01, color = #BBBBBB, width = 1, extend = extend.both)
```

I really cannot figure out how to draw the line so it extends from bottom to top for any indicator, i.e. those indicators that are in separate windows. I found the above code in an example, and it works for the main chart window. Parameter 2 and 4 in the line.new is y1 and y2, and somehow "close" and "close * 1.01" in combination with "extend = extend.both" magically works in the main chart window. Don't ask me why...

But how could I have generic code in this library that also work in a indicator in a separate window, as I would like to call the function from all my indicators to get a continuous vertical lines over all indicators and main chart?

All the best
Tommy

I searched all over but could not really find a way to do it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear. I am asking for a way to have a vertical line span all the way from bottom to top of a custom indicator, that is in a separate window (not overlayed on the main chart)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the background color.

```
bgcolor(condition ? color.blue : na)
```

Comment: bgcolor, was actually a very good alternative to the line.new, which gets rid of the y-scaling problem (as it always draw color for the whole bar from chart bottom to top). Thanks!